# Missing required parameter for [Route: verification.verify]

Tags: laravel, laravel-fortify

On a project I have I am using Fortify as my BE. I need a multilingual app, therefore I added the
`'prefix' => {locale}'` to config/fortify.php.

Login, registering, and 2FA, are working ok, but the problem arrives with the email verification process.

If I try to click on the link received by email, it goes to the `/email/verify` and returns a forbidden page error.

Then if I request to get another verification email it returns the error displayed on the title of the question.

Probably it has something to be with the locale parameter because when I run route::list, the `verification.verify` route is displayed with the endpoint of `{locale}/email/verify/{id}/{hash}`, so I assume that the link on the request another mail is causing the error since it is referenced as `/email/verify/{id}/{hash}`.

So does anyone know how to change it?
Or has anyone faced a similar problem regarding Fortify and these localization routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do was to customize some of the default Fortify functions, extending some classes in order to add the locale parameter to them.

When a new user is registered (event) it sends the verification email (listener), so I had to configure the files involved in this flow.

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

class SendEmailVerificationNotification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;
    
    public function handle(Registered $event)
    {
        if ($event->user instanceof MustVerifyEmail && ! $event->user->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            $event->user->sendCustomVerificationEmailNotification();
        }
    }
}
```

And create the function sendCustomVerificationEmailNotification on the user's model and the notification CustomVerificationNotification that will be sent.

```
public function sendCustomVerificationEmailNotification()
    {
        $this->notify(new CustomVerificationNotification);
    }
```

```
<?php
namespace App\Notifications;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class CustomVerificationNotification extends VerifyEmail
{
    protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
    {
        if (static::$createUrlCallback) {
            return call_user_func(static::$createUrlCallback, $notifiable);
        }

        return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
            'verification.verify',
            Carbon::now()->addMinutes(Config::get('auth.verification.expire', 60)),
            [
                'locale' => app()->getLocale(),
                'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
                'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Then in case, the user wants an additional verification email notification, this is handled through a function on the EmailVerificationNotificationController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\EmailVerificationNotificationController;

class CustomEmailVerificationController extends EmailVerificationNotificationController
{
    /**
     * Send a new email verification notification.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            return $request->wantsJson()
                        ? new JsonResponse('', 204)
                        : redirect()->intended(Fortify::redirects('email-verification'));
        }

        $request->user()->sendEmail();

        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new JsonResponse('', 202)
                    : back()->with('status', 'verification-link-sent');
    }
}
```